# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$, then $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded above.

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \infty$, then $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded above?

My approach is to prove it using contrapositive, which is assuming that if $\{a_n\}$ is bounded above, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n \neq \infty$.

I know that if $\{a_n\}$ is bounded above, then there exists a $u\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a_n\le u$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

But I'm not sure how to proceed to get a conclusion where $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq\infty$. However, I know that we say $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq\infty$ if there exists an $M>0$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $n\ge N$ such that $a_n\le M$.

Any suggestion will help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$?

Comment: Continue by picking an $N \in \Bbb{N}$ greater than $u$ (which you can, by the Archimedean property).

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ if for all $M>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\ge N$, then $a_n>M$.

Comment: Using your approach by the Archimedean Property, for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\ge N, \frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. Then I let $\epsilon = u$ so that $N>u$. Then, for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $M>0$ such that if $n\ge N, a_n \le M$. Is that how I come up to the conclusion? I'm not sure with the last part. @user780985

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224977/if-the-sequence-of-real-numbers-a-n-n-1n-infty-is-convergent-then-a-n?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $M = u$ (it doesn't have to be positive). Given any $N \in \mathbb N$, take $n = N$ (it doesn't really matter which one we pick), which certainly satisfies $n \geq N$. Then $a_n \leq u = M$, as desired.